I'm having trouble implementing a custom vibration plugin in Cordova
I created a custom vibration plugin, and it needs to be customized due to company requirements. However, when I try to implement it in the Android application using Cordova, it throws an 'vibration error: class not found' (vibration error: class not found), and I don't understand why. I believe I have configured the files correctly.
Here's a sample of them.
plugin.xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<plugin id="cordova-plugin-vibration" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://apache.org/cordova/ns/plugins/1.0"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <name>VibrationPlugin</name>
    <description>Plugin for vibrating the device</description>
    <license>MIT</license>
    <keywords>vibration, vibrate, cordova</keywords>
    <platform name="android">
        <config-file parent="/manifest" target="AndroidManifest.xml">
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
        </config-file>
        <source-file src="src/android/VibrationPlugin.java" target-dir="src/com/example/VibrationPlugin" />
    </platform>
    <js-module src="www/VibrationPlugin.js" name="VibrationPlugin">
        <clobbers target="cordova.plugins.VibrationPlugin" />
    </js-module>
</plugin>

package.json
{
    "name": "cordova-plugin-vibrationplugin",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "description": "An Android Cordova plugin that allows users to vibrate the device with different effects.",
    "cordova": {
        "id": "cordova-plugin-vibrationplugin",
        "platforms": [
            "android"
        ]
    },
    "repository": {
        "type": "git",
        "url": ""
    },
    "keywords": [
        "Vibration",
        "Vibrate",
        "Cordova",
        "ecosystem:cordova",
        "cordova-android"
    ],
    "engines": [
        {
            "name": "cordova",
            "version": ">=3.0.0"
        }
    ],
    "author": "user",
    "license": "MIT",
    "bugs": {
        "url": ""
    },
    "homepage": ""
}

file in www/VibrationPlugin.js
var exec = require('cordova/exec');

var VibrationPlugin = {
    vibrate: function(successCallback, errorCallback) {
        exec(successCallback, errorCallback, 'VibrationPlugin', 'vibrate', []);
    }
};

module.exports = VibrationPlugin;

file in src/android/VibrationPlugin.java
package com.example.vibrationplugin;

import org.apache.cordova.CallbackContext;
import org.apache.cordova.CordovaPlugin;
import org.apache.cordova.PluginResult;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.VibrationEffect;
import android.os.Vibrator;

public class VibrationPlugin extends CordovaPlugin {

    private static final String DURATION_LONG = "long";

    @Override
    public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext) {
        // Verify that the user sent a 'vibrate' action
        if (!action.equals("vibrate")) {
            callbackContext.error("\"" + action + "\" is not a recognized action.");
            return false;
        }
        
        // Extract message and duration from arguments
        String duration;
        try {
            JSONObject options = args.getJSONObject(0);
            duration = options.getString("duration");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            callbackContext.error("Error encountered: " + e.getMessage());
            return false;
        }
        
        // Vibrate the device
        try {
            Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator) cordova.getActivity().getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
            if (vibrator != null) {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                    VibrationEffect effect = VibrationEffect.createOneShot(1000, VibrationEffect.EFFECT_DOUBLE_CLICK);
                    vibrator.vibrate(effect);
                } else {
                    // For devices below Android Oreo, fallback to simple vibration
                    vibrator.vibrate(1000);
                }
                callbackContext.success();
            } else {
                callbackContext.error("Vibrator service not available.");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            callbackContext.error("Error while vibrating: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        
        return true;
    }
}

I don't understand why it keeps showing me the error that it can't find the class. I see that everything is configured correctly. I appreciate any help, thanks!
I've already tried changing the class names, redoing the entire plugin, modifying names, and I still can't fix it.
